# Find functions satisfying the given equations

Tags: real-analysis

The following question is from the book "Methods of Real Analysis" By Richard R Goldberg.

Let
$$f(x) = 2x         \    ( - \infty  < x < \infty  )$$

Can you think of functions g and h
which satisfy the two equations

$$g \circ f = 2 g . h$$

$$h \circ f = h^2 - g^2$$ ?

After trying several functions I observed that the peculiar format appears in Trigonometry viz formulas for double angles.

So I stumbled upon the solution as
$g(x) = sin (x)$ and
$h(x) = cos (x)$.

I assume my answer is correct. But what I want to know is whether there is some systematic procedure for solving this problem ?
The book does not provide any sample solved problems of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the function defined by
$$\varphi(x)=h(x)+ig(x)$$

Then $$\varphi(2x)= h(2x)+ig(2x)=h^2(x)-g^2(x) + 2ih(x)g(x)= (h(x)+ig(x))^2 = \varphi(x)^2$$

All the solutions of this equation give solution of your original problem : for example, $\varphi(x) = \exp(ix)$ gives the solution you found ($h=\cos$ and $g=\sin$), but there are much more solutions : $\varphi=0$ and $\varphi=1$ give also trivial solution ($h=1$ and $g=0$, and $h=g=0$ respectively), and for all $z=a+ib \in \mathbb{C}$, $\varphi(x)=\exp(zx)$ gives the solution $h(x)=\exp(ax)\cos(bx)$ and $g(x)=\exp(ax)\sin(bx)$.

All these solutions have the same form, but if you don't restrict the class of functions you are looking for, however, I think there can exist much more solutions to this equation.

Comment: Thanks @TheSilverDoe but I did not follow the step  
$$\varphi(2x)= h(2x)+ig(2x)=h^2(x)-g^2(x) + 2ih(x)g(x)= (h(x)+ig(x))^2 = \varphi(x)^2$$  
and I want to know how you thought of this. Could you please help me in understanding the thought process.

Comment: First step is definition of $\varphi$ ; the second one is the hypothesis on $h \circ f$ and $g \circ f$ (remember that $f(x)=2x$ !) ; third one is just the classic developpment of $(a+b)^2$ ; and fourth one is again the definition of $\varphi$. What makes me think of the trick is that I wanted to put together the two conditions : first idea was just to add them, and then the RHS would have become $h^2-g^2+2gh$... which is nearly $(h+g)^2$, but there is the minus sign. So to have a good form, I thought of adding $ig$ rather than $g$ to get the minus sign. So I thought of considering $h+ig$.